# best practice for session timeouts and persistent login in php

Tags: php, ajax, session, cookies, autologin

I have persistent login in my website so if user checks the "remember me" while login process,  set cookies to keep user alive all the times in that browser..

There are two routes to access to any page.. If it's not ajax request, requests go through index.php but if request is ajax it's just go through ajax.php.

To handle user request first I check session that whether userid stored or not, if session holds user there is no problem, request will be completed.
But if there is no current user id in session, I checked to cookie for autologin, if i can login user through cookie, force to login automatically with cookie data, and set Session with userid while user doesnt do anything..

Right now to handle it, I do the same process at the top of index.php and ajax.php like this;

```
class SessionManager
{
    private function __construct()
    { ; }

    public static function getSessionUser()
    {
        $user = NULL;

        if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
            $user   = $_SESSION['user'];
        else
        {


 /* Get username from cookie, and login it and set Session with user if it's possible otherwise do nothing Session is empty */
            getUserFromCookie();
            if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
                $user   = $_SESSION['user'];
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

In index.php;

```
$user = SessionManager::getSessionUser();

if(!isset($user))
{
   include dirname(__FILE__)."/controllers/login_controller.php";
}
```

and in ajax.php;

```
$user = SessionManager::getSessionUser();

if(!isset($user))
{
   echo json_encode(array("error" => true, "type" => NOT_ALLOWED, "message" => "User should login"));
}
```

So it works in all cases (I guess :)) , but what I wondering is what's the best practice to handle it? Any other ideas?

Comment: As the getUserFromCookie-function isn't included, it's hard to tell what is happening their, but make sure that you have more validation than just looking for the username in the cookie, otherwise it would be quite easy to login to any account by creating a cookie of your own.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson thanks man I'm really aware about cookie issue, it's just for test, I'm also researching about it.. But the above question it's inclueded, I just didnt mention to inclusion code for SessionManageer class, and there is actually no problem with it, I am just asking for the imporovement :)

Comment: See my answer for an example on how to improve security when using persisten cookies in PHP.

Comment: ok thanks for the link, what about checkin session values and try to log in user with cookie at the top of index.php and ajax.php ? Should i implement it with like this? Or any other way which is better?

Comment: Yeah, I believe that is just fine if you want to verify the user on the index page and through ajax only. If you want to verify the user on more pages, it might be a good idea to keep the verification logic in a separate file, and include that file at the top of each page where you want to verify the user. That way you only have the verification logic in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example of how to create persistent login with PHP, where the database is used in combination with a cookie, to verify that the cookie is authentic:

http://jeremycook.ca/2010/03/28/creating-a-persistent-login-mechanism/

Comment: Darn. jeremycook.com seems to no longer exist.